# How to have an input [type=date] with text in center and no icon?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
 :host input[type=date] {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            align-items: right;
            justify-content: right;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: white;
            border: 0px;
            z-index: -1;
            text-align: right;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
        }
</style>
```

[my date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6yT9.png)

also how do i move my datepicker behind? the shadow from the top headers are messing with my OCD.

below is my html strucuture.

```
<div>
    #shadow-root
    <div>
        <input type="date">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

WebKit makes available some selectors that allow extra changes on the elements.

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
}
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: if i add display:none; the datepicker doesnt show calendar when i click on it. this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `<input type="date">` by  `<input type="text">` add an event onfocus to get the value of date in the text box.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" onfocus="(this.type='date')" style="text-align:center;">
```

**How did you get the table from this code?**